# Exam class: write details of points with \totalpoints

Tags: exam

I use the exam class to produce exams for students, and I want to make a kind of questions, which puts in front the total points, but given detailed. I give an example:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\pointformat{}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion}. [Points of question \thequestion: \totalpoints]\hfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
\part[3]
\part[2]
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

[image]

I want to obtain, as output, the detailed points of the question, so precisely something like:

```
[Points of question 1: 3+2=5 points]
```

How can I obtain this ?

Comment: The information is stored on the aux files as `\gdef\pointsofq@i{5}`.  Alas, no points per part are so saved.

Comment: So we must install a similar command storing the information on the aux file for parts... something like `\gdef\pointsofpartofq{.}`..  I'm not a programmer but I think that it's not very difficult.. It's surprising that this macro does not exist because it's useful, I think !

Comment: For idea ! I found in `exam.cls` the command `\def\do@cvloop{...}` which seems to do the loops for computing `\totalpoints`

Comment: I haven't found `exercise@parts` in exam.cls. where is it ?

Comment: The macro `\def\begingradingrange` seems to do something like my purpose

Comment: Oops, I was digging through eqexam.

Comment: I don't know this package. I will read about it

Comment: If you know that this package does the task, I can migrate to it without any problem !

Comment: No, eqexam was a mistake.  I searched for `\let\parts` and wound up in that file.  In exam class parts is globally defined, although \part is redefined every time. Truth it, I just bought a book (Oathbringer) and won't be much use until I finish it.

Comment: Nice book so have a good lecture. Thanks for your disponibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key was figuring out the `\@doitem` was actually processing the argument.  While it is defined globally, I only want to modify/replace it for parts.

The `\expandafter`s are to expand `\else` and `\fi` first.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\pointformat{}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion}. [Points of question \thequestion: \details\totalpoints]\hfill}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\details}{\@ifundefined{details@\roman{question}}{}{\csname details@\roman{question}\endcsname =}}

\newcommand{\@details}{}% reserve global name

\let\normal@parts=\parts
\let\endnormal@parts=\endparts
\renewenvironment{parts}% no arguments?
 {\xdef\@details{\@empty}% initialize
  \normal@parts
  \let\normal@part=\@doitem
  \let\@doitem=\my@part
 }{%
  \endnormal@parts
  \ifx\@empty\@details
  \else
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\details@\roman{question}{\@details}}
  \fi
 }

\newcommand{\my@part}[1][\@empty]{%
  \ifx\@empty#1\relax
    \expandafter\normal@part
  \else
    \ifx\@empty\@details
      \xdef\@details{#1}%
    \else
      \xdef\@details{\@details +#1}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\normal@part\expandafter[\expandafter#1\expandafter]%
  \fi
}%
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[5]
\question
\begin{parts}
\part[3]
\part[2]
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just saw your answer. Thank you for your ingenious answer

Comment: if there is macros like this one in "Oathbringer"'s I'll read all of them in one night

Comment: I don't know how many pages it comes to but the Kindle was 22MB.

Comment: If I count about 15-20 Ko for a mathematical pdf page, it will be inhuman to read all this in one night !