# Macro for computing subtotal (hide subtotal)

Tags: macros, environments, exam

I've been trying to modify the following code which I have obtained from  [Macro for computing subtotal Tex Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424968/exam-class-macro-for-computing-subtotal-marks).

My MWE with my not so great solution.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Finds subtotal of all subparts %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Solution by John, K %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\subtotal}{\@ifundefined{subtotal@\roman{question}@\roman{partno}}%
{}%
{\csname subtotal@\roman{question}@\roman{partno}\endcsname}}

\new@hlfcntr{part@subtotal}

\let\normal@subparts=\subparts
\let\endnormal@subparts=\endsubparts
\renewenvironment{subparts}% no arguments?
{\set@hlfcntr{part@subtotal}{0}%
\normal@subparts
\let\normal@subpart=\@doitem
\let\@doitem=\my@subpart
}{%
\endnormal@subparts
\ifnum\c@part@subtotal>0
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\subtotal@\roman{question}@\roman{partno}%
{\prtaux@hlfcntr{part@subtotal}}}%

\fi
}

\newcommand{\my@subpart}[1][\@empty]{%

\ifx\@empty#1\relax
\expandafter\normal@subpart
\else
\ifx\@empty\@details
\else
\addto@hlfcntr{part@subtotal}{#1}%
\fi
\expandafter\normal@subpart\expandafter[\expandafter#1\expandafter]%
\fi
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\hidepoints}{\pointformat{}}  % Hides my points

\newcommand{\showpoints}{\pointformat{\textbf{\thepoints}}} % Shows my points

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

%%%%%%%%%%% The problem below %%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\question
This is my problem
\begin{parts}
    \part[\subtotal] I don't want to see the subtotal of 5. % I don't want to see the \subtotal on my paper, but I need it to tell LaTeX as this parts total points is the sum of the subparts below.
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[2] This subpart has 2 points.
        \subpart[3] This subpart has 3 points.
    \end{subparts}

This is  another problem

\part[\subtotal] I don't want to see the subtotal of 2. % I don't want to see the \subtotal on my paper, but I need it to tell LaTeX as this parts total points is the sum of the subparts below.
\begin{subparts}
    \subpart[1] This subpart has 1 points.
    \subpart[1] This subpart has 1 points.
\end{subparts}

\end{parts}

\droptotalpoints % Another problem as a result is Why the total points for Question 1 = 12 when it should be 7 (5+2)?

%%%%%%%%%% My current work around for the above problem below %%%%%%%%%

\question This is my not so great solution.
\hidepoints % I have hidden by \subtotal result.
\begin{parts}
    \part[\subtotal] % I don't want to see the \subtotal on my paper, but I need to tell latex that this part is the sum of the subparts below.
    \showpoints % Now i have to show points or else the \subparts won't be dispalyed.
    
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[2] 
        \subpart[3] 
    \end{subparts}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

***The Problem**

I can work around showing and hiding the subtotal of all my subparts manually by adding `\hidepoints` and `\showpoints` between my `\parts[\subtotal]` commands, but I noticed that if I have 2 subparts within a question, the total points for that question is calculated incorrectly.

Ideally I would like to come up with a solution that:

a) auto hides the `\subtotal` command.
b) calculates the correct points for the question.