# `kaobook` and `exam` class conflict: \marginnotes shift halfway off page

Tags: margins, exam, incompatibility, books, kaobook

Hoping to combine the best of the `exam` class with the `kaobook` class, I took the [Overleaf example document for Kaobook](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook) and added `exam.cls` with an `\import{exam}` command in the preamble. This worked perfectly aside from one problem: Margin notes are all translated right, half-way off the page.

[image]

[image]

I would like to provide a minimal working example, but both the basic `kaobook` example and the `exam.cls` file are too large to paste here. As an alternative, I hope it would be acceptable to share a link to the Overleaf project in this situation:

https://www.overleaf.com/9928673816cfkzkrnqhjns

Does anyone have any suggestions how to could prevent `exam.cls` from translating marginnotes off the page? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Exam class does odd things with the margins, so I'm not surprised if there are conflicts.  See "Changing the page margins" on page 100 of the manual.  You might look at the exercise package instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I wish I could find the part of `exam.cls` that screws up the margins. As for switching, I have spent a very long time developing questions and solutions and diagrams with answer plots within the exam class, so I am apprehensive to switch away from it.

Comment: Fixing this would require a complete re-write of exam class.  More precisely, to make it compatible with marginnotes one would have to totally change how exam class handles margins.

Comment: Could one comment the part of the `exam.cls` that handles margins, and keep everything else?

I would like to keep grade tables for cover pages of exams, `\printanswers` commands (like `\answerplot` that hides/shows nodes in a tikzpicture, `\solutiontable` that hides/shows answers in the tabular environment, etc.), `\solutionorlines` and `\answerline[]` and `\fillin[]` commands for fill in the blanks, `\choice` and `\correctchoice` for multiple choice questions, etc.? All of these features are important to me but I would be happy to delete the margin stuff from the exam class. Thanks again.

Comment: First, why don't you look at the manuals for the exercise (2014) and exercises (2017) packages (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf and http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exercises/exercises.pdf).  Trying to treat a document class as a package is a very bad idea to begin with, and exam class is one of the worst (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402863/exam-class-write-details-of-points-with-totalpoints/404088?r=SearchResults&s=13|41.0349#404088 for example).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I took your advice and considered moving away from `exam` in favor of `exercise`. However this package isn't compatible with `kaobook` either! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602947/make-exercises-package-compatible-with-kaobook